# How to retain the custom popup layout in Sugarcrm?

Tags: popups, layout, sugarcrm

I am using Sugarcrm 6.2.4 and trying to retain the custom Accounts popup that I have created for other custom module. The popup comes fine but when I click on Search button, the custom layout that I have made goes away. I can see that the default Accounts popup take-over my custom popup. The url also gets erased (that is the reason it came the default popup).

Can anyone having similar issue? Can anybody fixed this issue already? Please, help!